# Not getting Publishing Tab on template selection in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, enterprise-wiki

I am trying to create enterprise wiki by creating a subsite, but I am unable to find out the Publishing Tab. 
[image: Picture Goes here]

So, How can I get that? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: On the Site Collection Features page, next to Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure or SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure (depending on your version of SharePoint), click Activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Enterprise Wiki template is unavailable when you create a new SharePoint subsite](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2691485/enterprise-wiki-template-is-unavailable-when-you-create-a-new-sharepoi)

To resolve this issue, turn on the Publishing feature at the site collection level. To do this, follow these steps:

1. On the Site Actions or Settings menu (depending on your version of
   SharePoint), point to Site Settings, and then click Modify All Site
   Settings.

   Note If you do not see additional items when you point to Site
   Settings, click Site Settings.
2. If you are not at the root of your site, under Site Collection
   Administration, click Go to top level site settings.
3. On the Site Settings page, under Site Collection Administration,
   click Site collection features.
4. On the Site Collection Features page, next to Office SharePoint
   Server Publishing Infrastructure or SharePoint Server Publishing
   Infrastructure (depending on your version of SharePoint), click
   Activate.

Comment: @SandeepAnand  Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the Publishing features to create enterprise wiki sites.

1) Go to Site Settings > Site collection features.

2) Activate the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature

[image]

3) After that, go to Site Settings again

4) Click on Manage site features and activate the 'SharePoint Server Publishing' feature

[image]

Reference - [Activate publishing features in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/activate-publishing-features-in-sharepoint/)